# fetch() method doesn't work with Parse.com (similar to Backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I am making simple Todo application. I want to fetch data from Parse.com. The table is as below:

[image]

And I tried to fetch data, but this doesn't work:

```
 Parse.initialize("xxxxxx", "xxxxx");

 var Task = Parse.Object.extend({
    ...
 });

 var Tasks = Parse.Collection.extend({
    ...
 });

 var TaskView = Parse.View.extend({
    ...
 });

 var TasksView = Parse.View.extend({
    ...
 });

 var AddTaskView = Parse.View.extend({
    ...
 });

 tasks = new Tasks;
 tasks.query = new Parse.Query(Task);
 tasks.fetch();
 console.log(tasks.toJSON()); // I want to retrieve tasks but returns '[]'

 addTaskView = new AddTaskView({
   collection: tasks
 });

 tasksView = new TasksView({
   collection: tasks
 });

 $('#tasks').html(tasksView.render().el);
```

The whole page is here (**JSbin**): http://jsbin.com/iDociSu/2/edit

Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: `fetch` is an AJAX call and "A" is for "asynchronous". Trying binding to events on `tasks` so that you will be notified when you get data back from parse.com

Comment: Thank you mu, I was helped by you many times. I tried also jQuery Async Syntax as $.when and .done but the result was same.

Comment: `$.when(tasks.fetch()).done(function() {console.log(tasks);});
` worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Cheers. You can also bind to Backbone events on `tasks`.